# Is there any Application to view the Contents which are Saved to Offline?

Tags: ipad

From an Application, I Saved the PDF Contents to Offline.
Now, Exit from the Application.
Are there any App's to View the Offline Saved Content from outside the Application.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Applications cannot open the content of other applications on iOS. The document are tied to their app. Some of them can export the file to other apps. But that's it.